# How to draw a line on an existing region using RegionPlot with manipulate?

Tags: plotting, manipulate

`line1 = Table[{x, z + 1}, {x, 0, 2}]; Manipulate[ RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 + z < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},  Epilog -> {Red, Line[line1]}], {{z, 0.5}, 0, 1}]`[image]when I add an new variable using manipulate, it will be wrong. what should I do?[image]

Comment: hard to copy code from an image so it would be better to also paste the source code used.

Comment: Thank you. I have added it.line1 = Table[{x, z + 1}, {x, 0, 2}];
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 + z < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Line[line1]}], {{z, 0.5}, 0, 1}]

Answer (score 5):

Next time please paste the code used. Since it is small, I retyped it now.

The problem is that you have global z and control variable also called z. These should not be mixed.  Here is one workaround. Other workaround are possible. And always use `TrackedSymbols`

[image]

```
line1=Table[{x,z+1},{x,0,2}]
Manipulate[
   RegionPlot[x^2+y^2+z0<1,{x,0,2},{y,0,2},Epilog->{Red,Line[line1/.z->z0]}],
   {{z0,0},0,1},
   TrackedSymbols:>{z0}
]
```

I do not like mixing globals with Manipulate. Better is to use a Module inside Manipulate. Something like this and now you do not have to worry about different contexts

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{x, y, line1},
  line1 = Table[{x, z + 1}, {x, 0, 2}];
  RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 + z < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Line[line1]}]
  ],
 {{z, 0, "z"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {z}
 ]
```

**Update**

> When I change the x of line1 to start from 0.5 and end to 2, why only
> the line from 0.5 to 1.5 is displayed?

Because in your table the default increment is `1`. Change it to the following: (ps. no need to use `z0` anymore since we moved the code to inside the Manipulate.

Compare:

```
line1 = Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with

```
 line1 = Table[{x, y}, {x, 1/2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So if you want to go to `2` in the second case need to tell it to use increment of `1/2` and not `1`.

```
 line1 = Table[{x, y}, {x, 1/2, 2, 1/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{x, y, line1},
  line1 = Table[{x, z + 1}, {x, 0.5, 2, .1}];
  RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 + z < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Line[line1]}]
  ],
 {{z, 0, "z"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {z}
 ]
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a new problem. When I change the x of line1 to start from 0.5 and end to 2, why only the line from 0.5 to 1.5 is displayed? Manipulate[
 Module[{x, y, z, line1}, line1 = Table[{x, z + 1}, {x, 0.5, 2}];
  RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 + z0 < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, Line[line1 /. z -> z0]}]], {{z0, 0, "z"}, 0, 1, .1,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, TrackedSymbols :> {z0}]

Comment: @hu_rrr see update. hopefully this does what you want.

Comment: Yes, it's really helpful!